# Symlink fallback option

Tags: windows, powershell, autohotkey, symlink, fallback

I've bunch of symlinks that point to the %temp% directory that's on my RAMDISK, sometimes, I've to move the %TEMP% directory off RAMDisk and onto my SSD for whatever reasons. How do I make all Symlinks follow the new %TEMP% directory in SSD and vice versa?

PS: The files here aren't important, I don't care if directory or it's content get deleted in process, it's mostly temp/cache files of programs I use which write small files constantly.

Comment: You could make a directory junction at the location of your Ramdisk temp folder, pointing to your SSD temp folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions#junctions

Comment: @slothrop
I'd like to clarify that RamDisk %temp% folder is the "target" in this case. Linking SSD temp folder to RamDisk won't work incase the RAMDisk is unmounted, files can't be written as it doesn't exist anymore, I want the symbolic links to change target to SSD instead of RAMDisk when the drive is unmounted or TEMP/TMP paths are changed and reverse back when It's mounted again.

Comment: You could use `subst` command to create new drive in place of RAM disk that links to new TEMP path.

Comment: To add to zett42's helpful comment: I don't think you can define symlinks in terms of environment variables, only in terms of _literal_ paths. Thus, you must either _recreate_ your symlinks, or use an indirection mechanism such as suggested by zett42.